# Page with Javascript refreshing after script

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, form

I'm using Sharepoint Online through our company's Office 365 subscription. I wrote a page that generates a company standard email signature:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div.row {margin:0 0 5px 0;float:left;width:100%;padding:6px 0;}
div.row label {float:left;display:block;width:15em;padding:0 6px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
   <h1 id="pageTitle">Email Signature Generator</h1>
</div> 
<br>
<br>
<div class="row">
    <label for="txt_FullName" id="FullName-ariaLabel">Full Name</label>
    <input id="txt_FullName" name="txt_FullName" type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label for="txt_JobTitle" id="JobTitle-ariaLabel">Job Title</label>
    <input id="txt_JobTitle" name="txt_JobTitle" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label for="txt_DirectPhoneNumber" id="DirectPhoneNumber-ariaLabel">Direct Phone Number (xxx.xxx.xxxx):</label>
    <input id="txt_DirectPhoneNumber" name="txt_DirectPhoneNumber" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label for="txt_EmailAddress" id="EmailAddress-ariaLabel">Email Address:</label>
    <input id="txt_EmailAddress" name="txt_EmailAddress" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="row">
<input type="checkbox" id="social" checked="checked" />&nbsp;Include social media links and images?
</div>
<div class="row">
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit form" />
</div>

<div id="signaturePanel" style="display:none">
  <div style="font-size:10pt; font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;color:#0E5881;">
    Please copy/paste everything below the line into your email signature:
  </div>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div style="font-size:12pt; font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;color:#133467">
    <b><span id="fullNameOut"></span></b>
  </div>
  <div style="font-size:10pt; font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;color:#0E5881">
    <span id="jobTitleOut"></span>
  </div>
  <div style="font-size:10pt; font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;color:#656565">
    <b>Office:&nbsp;</b>123.123.1230&nbsp;&#124;&nbsp;Direct:</b>&nbsp;<span id="phoneNumberOut"></span>&nbsp;&#124;&nbsp;<b>Fax:</b>&nbsp;123.123.1230
    <br>
    <a id="emailOut" href="mailto:"></a>&nbsp;&#124;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.example.com">www.Example.com</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div style="font-size:20pt; font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;color:#676767">
    <b>Example.com</b>
  </div>
      <div id="socialOut" style="display:none">
    <a href="https://twitter.com"><img src="twitimg.png" alt="Twitter" height="54" width="54"></a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/"><img src="liimg.png" alt="LinkedIn" height="54" width="54"></a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="blogimg.png" alt="Blog" height="54" width="54"></a>
    </div>
  <br>

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("signaturePanel").style.display = "inherit";
  document.getElementById("fullNameOut").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txt_FullName").value;
  document.getElementById("jobTitleOut").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txt_JobTitle").value;
  document.getElementById("phoneNumberOut").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txt_DirectPhoneNumber").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("txt_EmailAddress").value;
  var emailOut = document.getElementById("emailOut");
  emailOut.innerHTML = email;
  emailOut.href = "mailto:" + email;
  if (document.getElementById("social").checked) {
    document.getElementById("socialOut").style.display = "inherit";
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It runs OK within a Sharepoint page, however, when it submits and shows the result it lasts for about 3 seconds and the page seems to refresh and the page goes back to scratch, removing the results. I've tried to add the code to the source of the page, use a Page Viewer Web Part, and embedding the code. It all has the same result. Is there a way to get this content to run in Sharepoint Online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out shortly after I posted. I changed

`<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit form" />`

to

`<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit form" />`

From what I was able to find, type="submit" posts the form content, which looks like a page refresh.